# i118n with Simpleform for date format from string

Tags: internationalization, simple-form

I am using jquery.datetime that inputs a date as a string into simpleform. It is supplying the date as %d %m %Y which is what I want but I am getting %m %d %Y because that is apparently the default for Simple Form:

The solution which is the same as for jquery datepicker is to add a custom input:

```
class DatePickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  def input
    value = object.send(attribute_name) if object.respond_to? attribute_name
    input_html_options[:value] ||= I18n.localize(value) if value.present?
    input_html_classes << "datepicker"

    super # leave StringInput do the real rendering
  end
end
```

This appears to be fine but it uses i118n to read the format I have a en.yml and a simple_form.en.yml initializer files under locales. I have tried adding:

```
datetime:
  formats:
   default: %d %m %Y
```

To both separately but when I do I get the following error message that says;

```
CAN NOT LOAD TRANSLATIONS
```

How can I modify my date time format?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have problem with `yml` formatting - it's one space instead of two. Try to change it to:

```
datetime:
  formats:
    default: %d %m %Y
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is partially correct but the format also needs to be quoted:

```
datetime: 
  formats:
    default: '%d %m %Y'
```